# Python + Appium : ios video recording is creating zero byte videos

Tags: automated-testing, python, mobile-automation, ios, behave

**Background** :
I am trying to record video on iOS using MacOS with M1.

**Problem** :
I am able to record video but after saving I can see video size is "Zero byte". I have not seen any error so far in a code or automation test and even on appium server :(

Anyone has observe this kind of behavior and already aware about fix?

Comment: Did you check permissions on the folder where you are trying to save the file?

Comment: yes, have req permissions for the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#Solution :

There are two appium native methods used for recording video on iOS platform irrespective of whether we are recording on simulator or real device?

1. context.driver.start_recording_screen()
2. context.driver.stop_recording_screen()

#Start - Video recording

```
context.driver.start_recording_screen(videoType='h264', videoQuality='high')
```

#Stop - Recording

```
video_file_name = f'{time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")}_{context.feature.name}_{context.scenario.name}.mp4'
video_file_path = os.path.join(video_recording_directory, video_file_name)

raw_video_data = context.driver.stop_recording_screen()
```

This raw data needs to be decoded from base64 inorder to create and save video file

```
with open(video_file_path, "wb") as fd:
                    fd.write(base64.b64decode(raw_video_data))
                log.info(f'{video_file_path} saved')
```